# Keyboard inputting extra characters

Tags: keyboard, autokey

I'm having a very frustrating issue with my 14.04 laptop due to water damage (lent my laptop to the wrong person). Something is inputting extra characters when certain keys are pressed. Everything works fine with an external keyboard.

o inputs a home (cursor goes to start of line) then the o, though a capital o will input 7 before the O.

l is *l (or *L)

9 is -9 (or "-(" )

and insert is p (this one i can live with).

I've been experimenting with AutoKey to try and find a workaround, but it doesn't seem possible to substitute strings that are shorter than the abbreviations. I also don't know how to deal with the o key using this method.

Comment: Are you sure it was water? Coffee or tea with sugar are the usual culprits for clogging up a keyboard but often removing the keyboard and rinsing in warm water and allowing to thoroughly dry will work.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to find a software work-around to a hardware failure and that's like steering towards the right after a car accident on the left instead of just repairing your car...

Just:

1. download the service manual of your laptop
2. order a replacement keyboard and have that wrong person pay for it
3. mount the keyboard yourself (the most expensive part is the mounting, not the keyboard itself)